# Add extra methods to directive form

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom form in Angular:

```
<form rp-form>
  <input type="text" value="one">
  <input type="text" value="two">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to add, using the angular directive, a method to handle the submission of the form and also the validity of the input fields:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('rpForm', function($compile) {
        return {
            scope: true,
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
                tElement
                    .attr({
                        name: 'testForm',
                        'ng-submit': 'mySubmit($element)'
                    })
                 return {
                     post: function(scope, element) {
                        // $compile(element[0])(scope); //causes infinite loop
                        console.log(scope);
                     }
                 };
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.mySubmit = function(e) {
                    console.log('my submit fired');
                };
           }
    };
});
```

I would like to be able to use the "mySubmit" method in the postLink function and also to be able to see in the scope the form directive object "testForm". Is this possible using angular?

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IxYPHRscfe1CnHocVx3X)**

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. Are you trying to add a submit method to the form from outside the directive- `<form ng-submit="doSomething()">`- or are you trying to get the directive to do that for you? Because you can just use ng-submit and not have to write your own directive.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson In the project I'm working on I cannot change the markup, I have to add the ng-submit in the directive code; the ng-submit does get added, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice but doable. The problem is you are isolating the scope with `scope: true`. Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

`compile` is primarily intended to modify the template, i.e. children DOM elements. And it doesn't look good here because a new directive is added to the compiled element itself, hence it should be re-compiled (it will obviously cause recursion, so recursive behaviour has to be controlled additionally).

And most straight-forward way is `rp-form` element directive with `<form ng-submit="mySubmit()" ng-transclude></form>` template.

There's no real need in `ng-submit` directive because it essentially [adds a listener to the element](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62). You can do it by yourself in (post)link. Since you cannot modify the markup, it will be

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('rpForm', function($compile) {
        return {
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.attr({
                    name: 'testForm'
                });
                element.on('submit', function () {
                    scope.$apply('mySubmit()');
                });
                console.log(scope);
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.mySubmit = function(e) {
                    console.log('my submit fired');
                };
           }
    };
});
```

And `mySubmit` is unnecessary on the scope if it is only used in `link`.